# Android image view from url

Tags: android, image, url

I am downloading an image from url, but the image is not changed after the download is complete.
I am entering code below, anybody experienced the same?

`Java` file

```
public class MyImgActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png");

    imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
 }
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try
      {
       InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
       Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
       return d;
      }catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Exc="+e);
       return null;
      }
}
}
```

`XML` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`Manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changing image url not displaying the image" ? Can you rephrase it?

Comment: Have you try to load jpg instead of png?

Comment: I am change "http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png" this url but not displaying image

Comment: does the jpeg loads or not also?

Comment: any exception in logcat? Which android OS you are using?

Comment: Now i am trying jpeg also but not displaying

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem    Not displaying exception in logcat. I am using 2.2 version

Comment: why cant you use "imgView.setImageURI(yourURL);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please Use below code for download and display image into imageview.

```
public class image extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://www.gophoto.it/view.php?i=http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: In logcat displaying this message08-29 14:04:53.046: D/dalvikvm(132): GC_EXPLICIT freed 743 objects / 42080 bytes in 163ms
08-29 14:04:58.096: D/dalvikvm(266): GC_EXPLICIT freed 362 objects / 19720 bytes in 182ms
08-29 14:05:05.196: D/dalvikvm(291): GC_EXPLICIT freed 274 objects / 12920 bytes in 76ms
08-29 14:09:21.957: D/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: @Kumar this code is working with any other url, so the problem is image size or in your url.

Comment: If i use this code my app will pause until the image is loaded. Im right?
A solution will be run opemHttpConnection in a AsyncTask?

Answer (score 3):

Following code working with the following url but its not working with your url.the problem is with your image size.Try with another url it will work.

```
public class MyImgActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        URL url = null;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg");
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        }catch (IOException e) {

        }
       imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp); 
      }

    }
```

Comment: imgView.setImageURI(yourURL); yourURL is the type of Uri only accepting? so i changed the code like Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);imgView.setImageURI(uri);, still not getting

Comment: ok Kumar i have edited the code this is working.If your image is exceeds the bitmap limit, it will not displayed.Hope there is not problem with the code.Your problem with your image

Answer (score 1):

```
 try
  {

   URL murl = new URL(url)
  URLConnection ucon = murl.openConnection();
  InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
   Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
   return d;
  }catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Exc="+e);
   return null;
  }
```

use this cose inside your download method and if the connection speed is slow use thread to donwload and hanlder to post the image...as explained by @Hiren

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

just change your URL to,

[URL](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin+Tendulkar.png)

onCreate

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2LTvCCufBKc/T3L3KgcTj2I/AAAAAAAABbQ/Ki60e1LU9sE/s1600/Sachin%2BTendulkar.png");
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }).start();
```

set image after downloading image using handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        Log.i("System out","after set the image...");
    }
};
```

Hope help you...