# unable to fetch image from url in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android image view from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172928/android-image-view-from-url)

I am trying to fetch the image from url and load in `imageView`, but I cannot encode the url string, please let me know how to encode this.

Please find the code & url  used for your reference.

URL: http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/%7BB690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A%7D_104_9169.JPG

#### Code

```
String link=URLEncoder.encode(urlStr);                    
bitmap=loadBitmap(link);

public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }        
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Code it will fetch the image from server

```
String URL = "http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/%7BB690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A%7D_104_9169.JPG"; 

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            final String msg = e1.getMessage();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                public void run() {  
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                }  
            });
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: is OpenHttpConnection is a method?

Comment: yep , i have added that function. Thanks and also sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, URLEncoder.encode(String) has been deprecated.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the url as below:

> ```
>   String URL = "http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/%7BB690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A%7D_104_9169.JPG";
>   String encodeUrl=URLEncoder.encode(URL, "utf-8");
>   private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
>     Bitmap bitmap = null;
>     InputStream in = null;
>     try {
>         in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
>         bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
>         in.close();
>     } catch (IOException e1) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         e1.printStackTrace();
>         final String msg = e1.getMessage();
>         handler.post(new Runnable() {  
>             public void run() {  
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
>             }  
>         });
>     }
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use below code for download and display image into imageview.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView my_img;
    Bitmap mybitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView mImgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1);

        DownloadImageFromURL mDisImgFromUrl = new DownloadImageFromURL(mImgView1);

        mDisImgFromUrl.execute("http://images.pcmac.org/SiSFiles/Schools/TN/JacksonMadisonCounty/RoseHillMiddle/Uploads/Locations/%7BB690E93E-F7C9-48AF-B72A-BFF944FA6D4A%7D_104_9169.JPG");

    }

    private class DownloadImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Loading...");
            pd.show();
        }

        public DownloadImageFromURL(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am doing it in asynchronous task and i am not getting the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have create example for [How to display image from URL](http://androidadvance.weebly.com/display-image-from-url.html). Use that example it works for me and i also check it by replace you image url.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar You have solve it or not ?