# How to get the Image to load from a URL ? (All answers on SO not working/deprecated)

Tags: android, image, url, web

I'm trying to build an app in which I want to show some images.

Before actually beginning, I already have a problem:
I can't get the imageview to load an image from a URL...

I know it's one of the most common questions on SO in this topic, and below I have some code I took off from :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173580

So, here's my entire MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage("http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-w7q2YocdYpY/UCeb6SCfGoI/AAAAAAAAAWY/nsXfzrGQjyA/s1600/Yahoo+Messenger.png");
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    
 
}
```

I have:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I've checked the links, changed them several times, checked my internet connection... and all I have is a blank screen. No reaction whatsoever.

I reckon I'm missing something pretty basic, do I need any other permission ?

Can you see anything wrong ?

**EDIT**

Using Picasso library:

Small code:

```
 ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imgView);
```

Large Logcat error, app crashes on startup.

```
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.exampl.aaa/com.exampl.aaa.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at com.squareup.picasso.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:317)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at com.exampl.aaa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4479)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
08-19 00:29:56.970: E/AndroidRuntime(4731):     ... 11 more
```

What target must not be null ?
...
Pls help :)

**EDIT2**
Forget the previous edit.
I didn't
setContentView(R.layout.main);

-.- .... On the other hand, Tasomaniac's answer worked great : Just added the Picasso jar and:

```
 ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imgView);
```

No Asynctask or complicated crap required.

thank you !

Comment: There are dozens of existing libraries for this. I like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [SmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/), but there are plenty of others to choose from.

Comment: Thank you for helping!, I will definitely look into those :-)

Comment: SLaks make a good point, are you getting NetworkOnMainThreadException, because it looks like that's what you are doing. If so you will need to do it in an AsyncTask or Service

Comment: Hmmm... I'm looking into Picasso - Can you help me out with that (check comments on "tasomaniac"s answer . Thank you !

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to initialize imgView in wrong section. Are you calling setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT); before the assignment?

Comment: I was "SettingContentView" after loading the image, hence it didn't have anything to work on, hence the Null error. Just put this before loading image and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Picasso library from Square Inc. It require the below 1 line code and thats it.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

https://github.com/square/picasso/

Comment: "context cannot be resolved to a variable" ... I've added the jar to the libs folder, But how exactly do I set up this context variable? (To what should I initialize it to- ?)

Comment: @user2678122: `context` here would probably be your `Activity`.

Comment: private static Context context; (And in OnCreate) context = getApplicationContext(); ------ This makes the app crash on start up. uhh... anything else ?

Comment: in your activity, you can just use "this" as your context

Comment: Ohh, lol. But it's still not working. I've updated the answer with the logcat output. Pls see.

Comment: Ohh whathe hell, I didn't "setContentView(R.layout.main);" .... It's all good now ! I have my image ! Thank you !

Comment: I was not here for half an hour. Glad you fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest using the following library, it takes care of image loading/caching and much much more, it just makes your life easier ;-)

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

```
//fetch and set the image from internet, cache with file and memory 
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

Features:

- Simple
- Memory & File Caching
- Down Sampling
- Zoomable (WebView)
- Fallback Image
- Preloading
- Animation
- Dynamic Aspect Ratio
- Avoid Duplicated Simultaneous Fetches
- Custom Callback

Answer (score 0):

I also have this permission, not sure it's necessary but worth a shot:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with yours, but here's my working code for this. I will have to check out those libraries.

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String str)
{
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(str);
        connection = openConnectionWithTimeout(url);
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new Options();
        // opt.inPurgeable=true;
        opt.inSampleSize = 6;
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream(), null, opt);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return bmp;
}

public static HttpURLConnection openConnectionWithTimeout(URL url) throws IOException
{
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(MAX_TIME);
    connection.setReadTimeout(MAX_TIME);
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Well, not if I don't do it on the UI thread, but good point, looks like that's what OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a third-party library, you can do this:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            try{
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.connect();
                InputStream input = con.getInputStream();
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                input.close();
                return bmp;
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.v("SHOW", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: @SLaks Use an `AsyncTask` , no issues :)

Comment: Can't believe, all this for just loading an image...  :/

Comment: Hehe, I actually have 3 apps on the market , Just never needed to use an image XD... I'm looking into Picasso - Can you help me out with that (check comments on "tasomaniac"s answer . Thank you !